# failed for validate the data from the request

Tags: laravel

i have request parameter like this in my update detail

```
#parameters: array:17 [▼
          "id" => "6DOX42ERxr"
          "_token" => "T2xvxyeQFmUzdRSYWzue8DEtt82pV93v9lIoAT84"
          "is_3rd_party" => null
          "sku" => "aaaa"
          "name" => "1122a"
          "approved_status" => "Waiting"
          "is_available" => "1"
          "status" => "1"
          "product_bundle_recomendation" => "1"
          "description" => "addd"
          "product_bundle_rank" => "1"
          "min_qty" => "1"
          "qty_step" => "1"
          "max_qty" => "100"
          "stock" => "100"
          "order_waiting_days" => "1"
          "order_waiting_max_days" => "10"
        ]
```

my request have been adding in my http request in my laravel code....

but when i check in my

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      dd($request);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
          'name' => 'required',
            //'price' => 'required',
            'status' => 'nullable',
            'description' => 'required',
            'images_thumb' => 'required|image|max:2048',
            'sku' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
          dd("gagal validator");
            return redirect()->back()
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
        }
```

when i only add until image_thumb the validator it is run well. but when i add 'sku'
my debug show "gagal validator" but in my code form the value is there and i have add the value of sku. so why like this ? can any one help me for fix it ?

here my form detail example

```
<div class="col-6">
                        {{ $form->setColLabel(4)}}
                        {{ $form->input('sku') }}
                        {{ $form->input('name') }}
                        {{ $form->input('approved_status') }}
                    </div>
```

Comment: did you add ```images_thumb`` ?

Comment: can you show us you full form code? cant see `image_thumb` field. Also make sure your form `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data`